# Automatically detect if a certain window becomes active?

Tags: autohotkey

I mean detect it without pressing a hotkey that will call the lines of code that will check it if said window is active

Below example works fine but pressing `4` is required.

```
4::
if WinActive("*Untitled - Notepad ahk_exe notepad.exe")
  {
      MsgBox, Found Notepad
  }
  else
  {
       MsgBox, Did Not Find Notepad
  }
  Return
```

I have also tried this, but it just spams me with MsgBoxes.

```
Loop, 50
  {
    if WinActive("ahk_class #32770")
      {
          MsgBox, Found Notepad
      }
      else
      {
           MsgBox, Did Not Find Notepad
      }
  }
```

Thanks.

Comment: See [SetTimer - Example#2](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm#ExampleWait).

Comment: @user3419297, That was just what I needed. Thanks!